# Nature of a function involving integrals to have a root in an interval

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Let $f: \mathbb R \to(0,1)$ be a continuous function. Then which of the following function(s) has/have the value $0$ at some point in the interval $(0,1)$?

\begin{align}
& e^x-\int_0^x f(t) \sin t \, dt \tag a \\[10pt]
& f(x)+\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t) \sin t \, dt \tag b \\[10pt]
& x-\int_0^{\pi - x} f(t) \cos t \, dt \tag c \\[10pt]
& x^9-f(x) \tag d
\end{align}
The correct options are $(c)$ and $(d).$

Now I understand that option d is correct.
How do we conclude that option (c) is correct as well?

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage as in my edits to the question.

Comment: Notice that $x^2$ goes from $0$ up to $1$ when $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, while $f(x)$ remains between $0$ and $1.$ Thus when $x=0,$ then $x^9-f(x)$ is negative and when $x=0,$ then $x^2-f(x)$ is positive. Hence $(d)$ is one of the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer : $\left(d\right)$ is easy.

If $g\left(x\right)=x^{9}-f\left(x\right)$, then, by assumption ($f\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\subset\left(0,1\right)$),
$f\left(0\right)<0$ and $f\left(1\right)>0$. $g$ being continuous,
it has to vanish somewhere in $\left[0,1\right]$, and it does not
vanish at $0$ nor at $1$.